# Know what program trigger other program in Windows

Tags: c, windows, powershell

I am in a developing and I require know if is possible know what program execute other program in Windows. I have search in many ways but do not find anything.
If someone know something like a register in Windows, a script in PowerShell, in C or whatever.

Comment: By "trigger"  - you mean "execute"?

Comment: Yes, the word is execute

Answer (score 1):

You want the parent process. You can find this through `Get-CimInstance`:

```
$PID = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'notepad.exe'"
Get-Process $PID.ParentProcessID | Select ProcessName

# Outputs
ProcessName   
-----------   
explorer
```

Comment: For example, I have a bot in python and this open explorer.exe, is there a way to know if this scpecific python script open it?

Comment: your bot has process id, substitute  it as a Parent

Comment: @Manuel, unfortunately `explorer.exe` is treated differently within windows - it will always have process `svchost.exe` or `services` as the parent.

Comment: I have the same problem. The process is WmiPRvSE, and this process has many instances, all of them with different PIDs. I need to know the trigger of one of them in specific